# How could I fix an error in R with library(WikipediR)?

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a wikipedia page text, but I am getting an error from the library(WikipediR). Here it is my code & error:

```
library(WikipediR)
wp_content <- page_content("en","wikipedia", page_name = "COVID-19 vaccine", 
                           clean_response = T, as_wikitext = T)
```

> Error in UseMethod("parse_response", x) :    no applicable method for
> 'parse_response' applied to an object of class "pcontent"

It runs with:

```
library(WikipediR)
wp_content <- page_content("en","wikipedia", page_name = "COVID-19 vaccine", 
                           clean_response = FALSE, as_wikitext = TRUE)
```

but it would not retrieve any information from the wikipedia page, which defeats the purpose of the NLP analysis that I am trying to perform.

Comment: `page_content("en","wikipedia", page_name = "COVID-19 vaccine", 
                           clean_response = FALSE, as_wikitext = TRUE)` Use this

Comment: It runs that way, but it does not get the data from the Wikipedia page for the analysis.